# Can a Unitary matrix be non-diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, unitary-matrices

It is known that all non-diagonalizable matrices are non-hermitian. However, my question is that, are there some unitary matrices that are non-diagonalizable. What are the conditions ?

Comment: The spectral theorem comes to mind

Comment: All Normal matrices are diagonalizable and all unitary matrices are normal. Hence, all Unitary matrices are diagonalizable. I think this is the answer.

Comment: But be careful of the context in which they are asking this. Maybe they want to trick you with the case of a field that is not algebraically closed. Then the failure is caused by the field not containing the eigenvalues.

Comment: @user85667 But the words “hermitian” and “unitary” certainly suggest that we’re working over $\Bbb C$, don’t they? Wouldn’t “self-adjoint” be expected in the general setting?

Comment: @TedShifrin Most commonly, they do, but better to be alert, since language isn't as uniform/strict as one would like it to be.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Hypothetically, we could be working with some subset or superset of $\mathbb{C}$ (for which the concept of "conjugate" would still apply), but breaks one of the field axioms.  But if so, any decent exam-writer should *say* what type of numbers they're using, lest people assume the "default" $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the terminology doesn't seems standardized. Seeing wikipedia it says that a unitary matrix is an isometry on a finite dimensional complex vector space, however if you see in wikipedia unitary operator one of it examples is a rotation operator in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So, if we assume that the underlying field is the complex field and the dimension of the vector space is finite we can pick the first definition stated above and so all unitary matrices will be diagonalizable.

However, if we go with the more general definition of unitary operator then we can say that not all unitary matrices are diagonalizable if the field is $\mathbb{R}$, by example many rotation matrices in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are unitary but doesn't have (real) eigenvalues, so they cannot be diagonalizable.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes because this is correct...

Comment: Generally, referring to "a unitary matrix" (whose inverse is its conjugate transpose) instead of "an orthogonal matrix" (whose inverse is its straight transpose) implies that you're working over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Dan this is not true. In infinite dimensional spaces the difference between unitary and isometry is that the first is invertible, but the second not necessarily. You don't need to assume a complete field to talk about unitary operators.

Comment: @Masacroso While what you say about infinite dimensions is true, I don't see how it is relevant to the question at hand. I would also assume that we are over $\mathbb C$ if the word unitary is used.